# Create Wildcard Pages with dynamic content

Tags: sxa, datasource, wildcards

I'm trying to create a page with a Wildcard item that displays different content depending on the url. That's why I created an item with a controller inheriting VariantsController.

But I can't change the data my variant will display. I don't know if I've gone for the simplest solution.

Comment: Refer the question: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15672/resolving-wildcard-item-and-show-the-presentation-detail-of-the-wildcard-item

Comment: You can follow the blog - https://sitecorerocksblog.wordpress.com/2016/11/15/resolve-wildcard-item/